# can't input chinese character when creating folder in debian 11

Tags: debian, input-method, fcitx

I have switched to the Pinyin input method,then to create new folder.
Environment:

```
debian@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
debian@debian:~$ dpkg -s  lxde
Package: lxde
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Installed-Size: 10
Maintainer: Debian LXDE Maintainers <pkg-lxde-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: lxde-metapackages
Version: 11
```

[image]

In the form , i can't type chinese characters in on my debian 11.

Same status on my debian 10,i can type  chinese characters in the form.
Environment:

```
debian@debian:$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
debian@debian:$ dpkg -s lxde
Package: lxde
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Installed-Size: 10
Maintainer: Debian LXDE Maintainers <pkg-lxde-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: lxde-metapackages
Version: 10
```

[image]

How to fix it in my debian 11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep fcitx only.

```
sudo apt remove ibus
sudo apt remove fcitx5
```

The fcitx-ui often removed,so re-install it.

```
sudo apt install  fcitx-ui-qimpanel
```